# Drag and Drop method not performing any actions, simply that was executing not doing any actions

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, codeception, codeceptjs

I'm just using I.dragAndDrop() method, it's not performing any actions. Simply it was passing without doing any actions

just small drag and drop function I'm trying to do, it was not throwing any errors.

And I'm included the drag and drop locator too, still not doing any actions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let Actions = webdriver.ActionSequence;
let driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

driver.get('your-website-url');

    let sourceElement = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('source-selector'));
    let targetElement = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('target-selector'));
    
    new Actions(driver)
        .dragAndDrop(sourceElement, targetElement)
        .perform();
```